# Where can I host my Ionic app (with CouchDB) to run in browsers?

Tags: windows, ionic-framework, browser, couchdb, hosting

I am developing an Ionic app.
It works both on Android and iOS.
I got a free trial period on a hosting site called Heroku, where I've put the content of the www folder of my project.
The website works but the interaction with the remote couchDB does not work, despite it works good on mobile phone.
Is there a reason?
Maybe Heroku doesn't support couchDB?

Thanks

Comment: What are the logs in the console when you use your website?

Comment: Failed to load http://IPADDRESS:5984/TABLE/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: You need to authorize CORS on your CouchDB

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling for days! It works now. For anyone else who could experience this issue, CORS must be enabled for all domains

Comment: Now I am facing the following problem: if I try to access this website through a smartphone, the interaction with the database doesn't work. But if I require desktop version, it works, and if later I come back to mobile version, it keeps working. Do you have any clue? Thanks

Comment: Mobile version is the same website or a mobile application?

Comment: The same website